# Find Questions/Wikis By Tag By User Reputation

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow, stack-exchange

One thing that would be neat would be to be able to read questions posted by users with a certain experience (ie. Reputation count) in StackOverflow.

I love browsing StackOverflow to learn about random topics or perfect some of my existing skills, it's a mine for good information. I already follow certain tags.

At the moment when you browser certain tags (ie. WPF), it's full of pretty noob questions, which I'm happy to read or answer whenever I can... However I'd like to see only questions posted by people more experienced or advanced in StackOverflow, that don't ask the questions already asked 10 times and who's questions might be a bit more challenging / deeper in the topics.

Maybe there is a way already that I'm not aware of...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way to do that now; if there were it would probably be a [search option](https://stackoverflow.com/search) like `reputation:10000`.

For now, you can use the Data Explorer to select all the posts that meet your requirements. For example, [all WPF posts by a user with at least 10k rep](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/402/questions-by-tag-and-minimum-asker-reputation?TagName=WPF&MinReputation=10000). It operates on the monthly SO data dump though, so it will be missing the newest posts (it was last updated at the end of June)